# Inserting PHP 7 variables into SQL Server

Tags: php, html, sql-server, database

I am sure this question has been asked. I have searched for the answer but I can't seem to find it.   I have this code to connect then INSERT data into a MS Sql Database from PHP .  It isn't working.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<?php
//Session Start
session_start();
include '/includes/dbconn.mssql.php';

ini_set('display_errors','On');
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
<?php        

        $sql = "INSERT INTO 
agents(fname,lname,date,dl1,ul1,lat1,jit1,dl2,ul2,lat2,jit2,dl3,ul3,lat3,jit3,UCN,ISP,IP,mmake,mmodel,[user],pass,email,winver,modem,mon1mk,mon1mdl,mon2mk,mon2mdl,headset,hmake,hmodel,webcam,prospect,[current],planul,plandl,station) "
                    . "VALUES('Janice','Smith','2/15/2019','10','10','1','1','10','10','1','1','10','10','1','1','333689','Xfinity','10.0.0.1','Ubee','100','admin','password','jane.smith@companyinc.com','null','null','Acer','100','AOC','5','1','Plantronic','54','1','0','1','150','50','28')";
            //      $sql = "INSERT INTO agents(fname,lname,date,dl1,ul1,lat1,jit1,dl2,ul2,lat2,jit2,dl3,ul3,lat3,jit3,UCN,ISP,IP,mmake,mmodel,user,pass,email,winver,modem,mon1mk,mon1mdl,mon2mk,mon2mdl,workspace,monitor1,monitor2,headset,hmake,hmodel,webcam,prospect,current,planul,plandl,station) VALUES('$fname','$lname','$date','$dl1','$ul1','$lat1','$jit1','$dl2','$ul2','$lat2','$jit2','$dl3','$ul3','$lat3','$jit3','$UCN','$ISP','$IP','$mmake','$mmodel','$user','$pass','$email','$winver','$modem','$mon1mk','$mon1mdl','$mon2mk','$mon2mdl','$workspace','$monitor1','$monitor2','$headset','$hmake','$hmodel','$webcam','$prospect','$current','$planul','$plandl','$station')";
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
            $echo = sqlsrv_rows_affected;
            if(!$result) {
    echo 'Your code failed. $echo';
}
else {
    echo 'Success! $echo'; 
}
?>
</html>
```

When i run the code in Edge it says

Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_query() in .... line 34

Line 34 being

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have any errors related to `undefined function sqlsrv_connect`? You should be getting that before sqlsrv_query. Make sure the sqlsrv extension [is installed](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php)

Comment: This is suspect too: `include '/includes/dbconn.mssql.php';` as it implies the `includes` directory is at the filesystem root, rather than relative to something else in PHP. That may be the case in your system, but seems unlikely and would be very uncommon.  And might explain why no got no prior error from `sqlsrv_connect()`.

Comment: You have display_errors turned on which is good, also just before that line set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to insert data into the cells with data and with variables.

```
     <?php

   $uploadDir = 'pics/';

   if(isset($_POST['upload'])){ 

       $fileName = $_FILES['monitor1']['name'];
       $tmpName  = $_FILES['monitor1']['tmp_name'];
       $fileSize = $_FILES['monitor1']['size'];
       $fileType = $_FILES['monitor1']['type'];

       $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;

       $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);

       if (!$result) {
           echo "Error uploading <strong>file</strong>";
           exit;
}


       $sql =  "INSERT INTO agents(fname,lname,employee_status,dl1,ul1,lat1,jit1,monitor1) "
               . "  VALUES('".$_POST['fname']."',
                        '" .$_POST['lname']."',
                        '" .$_POST['status']."',
                        '" .$_POST['dl1']."',
                        '" .$_POST['ul1']."',
                        '" .$_POST['lat1']."',
                        '" .$_POST['jit1']."',
                        '" .$_FILES['monitor1']."')";                            

              $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql);

              if( $result === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

   }

?>
```